# Equivalent of scala.concurrent.util.Unsafe in Scala 2.12

Tags: scala, scala-2.12

I have created empty instance of my object and then initialise it using run time values. Implementation was based on `scala.concurrent.util.Unsafe` in Scala 2.11 and it worked fine.

I understand `Unsafe` is bad and hence has been deprecated in Scala 2.12.

If it's deprecated then what's equivalent of `Unsafe` in Scala 2.12?

Comment: Can you share a bit more details about what you want to achieve? AFAIK `Unsafe` was removed for compatibilty with JDK9+ and there's no direct replacement (https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9381)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running on a JVM where `sun.misc.Unsafe` is still available (this will limit which JVMs you can run on, but so did using `scala.concurrent.util.Unsafe` so no immediate loss):

```
val unsafeInstance = // use in place of Scala 2.11 usages of scala.concurrent.util.Unsafe.instance
  classOf[sun.misc.Unsafe]
    .getDeclaredFields
    .filter(_.getType == classOf[sun.misc.Unsafe])
    .headOption
    .map { field => 
      field.setAccessible(true)
      field.get(null).asInstanceOf[sun.misc.Unsafe]
    }
    .getOrElse { throw new IllegalStateException("Can't find instance of sun.misc.Unsafe") }
```

Code is very slightly adapted from the Scala 2.11 source.

It's possible that this is an instance of spending so much time thinking about "could" that one didn't think about "should".